# Python betterproto, ability to NOT change variable names defined in *.proto files

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers, config, grpc

**The Question:**

Is there a way/config to retain the original variable names when compiling with betterproto?

**The Background**

I have a protocol buffers proto file that defines a runID variable like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package MyRequestProto;
    
message MyRequest {
            string runID = 1;
}
```

It is compiled into Python dataclasses using this command:

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc \
    -I./ \
    --python_out=./src \
    --grpc_python_out=./src \
    --python_betterproto_out=./src/protocol_buffers \
    ./protocol_buffers/*.proto
```

When I compile the proto file with betterproto the resulting variable is renamed to run_i_d:

```
@dataclass
class MyRequest(betterproto.Message):
    run_i_d: str = betterproto.string_field(1)
```

The grpc endpoint at the other end of the transmission is expecting the original variable name: runID.

Comment: What language|runtime is the server using? Was it generated from that proto too? The style guide (somewhat confusingly but presumably for multi-language support) recommends PascalCase for message names and snake_case for field names. The use of `runID` does not conform and it may be the cause of the problem. Sometimes `protoc` plugins provide a flag to override the default conversion. Alternatively have you tried using `run_id` in the proto to see what gets produced? See: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style#message_and_field_names

Comment: Thinking more about it `run_id` likely won't work as that should generate `run_id` methods in Python. Does the standard Python plugin generate the desired field names using `runID`? Unless betterproto has a configuration option, you may need to stick with the original plugin.